# Customer header is not coming in the response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

In my Jax-Rs(Jersey + Jetty) application, I've added some custom headers to the response so that I can use those at the client side. I'm using ResponseBuilder to achieve this.

```
     @Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CustomException> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomExceptionMapper.class);

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;


    @Override
    public Response toResponse(CustomException exception) {

        String errorKey = null;
        String errorArgs[] = null;

        // log stack trace
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred during the operation.", exception);
        if (exception instanceof MetadataServerException) {
                errorKey = ExceptionMapperUtil.checkForDBException(exception.getCause());
            if (errorKey != null) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .entity(MessageSourceUtils.getMessage(errorKey, errorArgs, ExceptionMapperUtil.getLocale(headers))).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
            }
        }

        if(ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(exception.getMessageKey()) && 
                (exception.getMessageArguments() == null || exception.getMessageArguments().length==0) ){
            exception.setMessageArguments(new Object[]{"while executing the operation"}); 

        }
        // prepare response to be sent to client
        return Response.status(ResponseCodeMapper.mapToStatusCode(exception)).
                entity(exception.getMessage(ExceptionMapperUtil.getLocale(headers))).
                type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).header("errorCode", exception.getMessageKey()).
                build();
    }
}
```

And also, I've confirmed that that the response object is getting built properly. However, for some reason, the returned response doesn't contain my custom header. Any clues as to to what is going wrong ?

Comment: Just checked with an implementation of a `ExceptionMapper` that I have running and one project and your code looks ok, very similar in fact. How are you reading the message in the client side? Are you using jersey client also? E.g. you are using `TEXT_PLAIN` as `type` in your response and might not be congruent in your client... Not really a clue, by maybe it would help that you post the client.

Comment: I used Mozilla rest client at the client side to check the response.

Comment: Ok. I've never used Mozilla rest client but I guess you can see the full message in there. As I say, you java code looks ok. No clues, sorry.